# Microsoft .NET Framework and TLS 1.2 creates a 'Handshake Failure' with haproxy

Tags: networking, ssl, haproxy

I'm unable to use `System.Net.WebRequest` for a request with TLS 1.2.
If I do so, I get an Exception `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.` and the protocol error `Handshake Failure`.

Connection over TLS 1.2 and authentication is working with Internet Explorer and Chrome.
OpenSSL can connect to this enpoint over TLS 1.2.

## Setup

1. Using ClientCertificates for authentication
2. Using non default Port
3. Using TLS 1.2
4. Endpoint is a haproxy but this is a blackbox
5. .NET 4.7 and C#

## Code snipplet

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var req = WebRequest.Create($"https://{host}:{port}");
((HttpWebRequest)req).ClientCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection(GetCertificate());
var requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
```

## Wireshark

*A text output from wireshark in the order the occure.*

**Client Hello**

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 207
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 203
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random: 5a292ab72d2173fc286aebe2c4cc991ee619e1cc81b5bb39...
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 60
            Cipher Suites (30 suites)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
            Extensions Length: 102
            Extension: server_name (len=43)
                Type: server_name (0)
                Length: 43
                Server Name Indication extension
                    Server Name list length: 41
                    Server Name Type: host_name (0)
                    Server Name length: 38
                    Server Name: [REMOVED]
            Extension: supported_groups (len=8)
                Type: supported_groups (10)
                Length: 8
                Supported Groups List Length: 6
                Supported Groups (3 groups)
            Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
                Type: ec_point_formats (11)
                Length: 2
                EC point formats Length: 1
                Elliptic curves point formats (1)
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=20)
                Type: signature_algorithms (13)
                Length: 20
                Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 18
                Signature Hash Algorithms (9 algorithms)
            Extension: SessionTicket TLS (len=0)
                Type: SessionTicket TLS (35)
                Length: 0
                Data (0 bytes)
            Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
                Type: extended_master_secret (23)
                Length: 0
            Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
                Type: renegotiation_info (65281)
                Length: 1
                Renegotiation Info extension
                    Renegotiation info extension length: 0
```

`Server Name: [REMOVED]` contains the right server name.

**Server Hello**

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 65
        Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
            Handshake Type: Server Hello (2)
            Length: 61
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random: 5a292ab7238205b2b8a2e6692abfd518a054515e53cd5b16...
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
            Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 21
            Extension: server_name (len=0)
                Type: server_name (0)
                Length: 0
            Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
                Type: renegotiation_info (65281)
                Length: 1
                Renegotiation Info extension
                    Renegotiation info extension length: 0
            Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
                Type: ec_point_formats (11)
                Length: 4
                EC point formats Length: 3
                Elliptic curves point formats (3)
            Extension: SessionTicket TLS (len=0)
                Type: SessionTicket TLS (35)
                Length: 0
                Data (0 bytes)
```

**Certificate**

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Certificate
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 3855
        Handshake Protocol: Certificate
            Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
            Length: 3851
            Certificates Length: 3848
            Certificates (3848 bytes)
```

**Server Hello Done**

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Key Exchange
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 589
        Handshake Protocol: Server Key Exchange
            Handshake Type: Server Key Exchange (12)
            Length: 585
            EC Diffie-Hellman Server Params
                Curve Type: named_curve (0x03)
                Named Curve: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                Pubkey Length: 65
                Pubkey: ...
                Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0401
                Signature Length: 512
                Signature: ...
```

**Multiple Handshake Messages**

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Multiple Handshake Messages
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 77
        Handshake Protocol: Certificate
            Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
            Length: 3
            Certificates Length: 0
        Handshake Protocol: Client Key Exchange
            Handshake Type: Client Key Exchange (16)
            Length: 66
            EC Diffie-Hellman Client Params
                Pubkey Length: 65
                Pubkey: ...
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Change Cipher Spec Protocol: Change Cipher Spec
        Content Type: Change Cipher Spec (20)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 1
        Change Cipher Spec Message
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 40
        Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message
```

This part is different when the internet explorer is used. In this case, there a lot if certificates listed.

```
    Handshake Protocol: Certificate
        Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
        Length: 3
        Certificates Length: 0
```

**Handshake Failure**

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)
        Content Type: Alert (21)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 2
        Alert Message
            Level: Fatal (2)
            Description: Handshake Failure (40)
```

I'm not sure about where to post (Serverfault vs. Stackoverflow), so I posted this here too https://stackoverflow.com/q/47697982/1776231